# mysql WHERE row = multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

is there a better way to select where shop_area = a series of different values - currently I am using php foreach on an array do output this

```
SELECT * FROM Shop_id WHERE scheduled = '0' && end_date >= CURDATE() && (shop_area = '757' OR shop_area = '804' OR shop_area = '540' OR shop_area = '252');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Shop_id
WHERE
   scheduled = '0'
   && end_date >= CURDATE()
   && shop_area IN('757','804','540','252');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`IN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

> ### expr IN (value,...)
>
> Returns 1 if expr is equal to any of the values in the IN list, else returns 0.

So something like:

```
... && shop_area IN('757', '804', '540', '252')
```

Answer (score 0):

... `WHERE shop_area in (804, 540, 252)`